# Command "doccano task" throws a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: doccano

I am trying to get doccano running on my computer.
I did the steps showing in the git repository. https://github.com/doccano/doccano

The last step "doccano task" throws an error.
That is why i am not able to upload any files to doccano.

Here is the error:
'''
*C:\Users\VictorMuench>doccano task
...
packages\kombu\transport\sqlalchemy_*init*_.py", line 61, in 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
File "c:\users\victormuench\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy_*init*_.py", line 10, in 
import sqlalchemy.exc as exceptions
File "c:\users\victormuench\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\exc.py", line 258
except Exception, e:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

'''

I am unable to find the caused error.
Can anyone help?

Thank you.